# Being Michalel Shabbos during a Psychotic attack

Tags: shabbat, repentance-teshuvah

If someone is michalel shabbos during a psychotic attack should he do teshuva for that chilul shabbos? Is there a difference between someone who remembers doing the aveirah and one with no recollection of the aveirah?

Comment: A person undergoing a psychotic attack, Chas v'shalom, lo aleinu, has no choice in the matter of what he/she does. Why would you think he would be punished for such an action? During that state it sounds like he would be like the halachic shoteh, who is not chayiv in mitzvos. Unless I've completely misunderstood what you're referring to by psychotic attack.

Answer (score 5):

Not all words are emerging from the same background, it is right insight of the secular langage itself. For instance, forensic psychiatry is not the result of medicine only, but also of the study of law.

Generally the term "psychotic" refer to medical terminology, "teshuva" refers to Jewish law, to guilt in accordance to Jewish law.

There is psychotic and psychotic.  Generally in strong acute P. Events the patient is 100% halachically defined as Shote and is patur from Teshuva.  But if the reason of the exacerbation is intentional interruption of  treatment this and this only need Teshuva. For most cases, they need to be examined accurately.

The definition of psychotic in DSM is not fully equivalent to the definition of Shoyte in halacha.  Some persons has not good reality testing but conserve a +- good judgment  concerning social behavior.  They are psychotic but not  Shote.

Regarding the secular law the definition concerning capacity is not an exact replication of medical diagnosis.

See Rambam Gerushin 2, 14:

> [The following rules apply when] a person is **troubled {terrified} by an evil spirit**, and at the time when his infirmity begins to take hold of him says: "Write a get for my wife." His statements are of no consequence, because his thoughts are not organized and settled. The same ruling applies to a person who has become as drunk as Lot.

See Edut 9, 9:

> A person who is mentally or emotionally unstable {from who the judgement is not ordered} is not acceptable as a witness according to Scriptural Law, for he is not obligated in the mitzvot. **We are not speaking about only an unstable {may be that *disorganized* is more accurate} person who goes around naked, destroys utensils, and throws stones. Instead, it applies to anyone whose mind is disturbed and continually confused when it comes to *certain matters* although he can speak and ask questions to the point *regarding other matters***. Such a person is considered unacceptable and is placed in the category of unstable people.

Regarding recollection of Avera, an other problem, see mishnayot in Shvuot, there are cases in which Korbanot, tsibur or yachid following the case, are adapted to problem of partial knowing.

The two above halachot show by their appearent discrepancy that the matter is not so easy to decide. There was [a famous Get in 1766-1767](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%94%D7%92%D7%98_%D7%9E%D7%A7%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%95%D7%95%D7%90) with several discussions about Shote.

See Mishpete Daat from Rabbi Moshe Mordechai Ferbstein edited in "Machon Shaar Hamishpat Jerusalem 5755 a comprehensive book about  dine Shote.

Comment: Where did you get these translations from? || What is the relevance of the efficacy of shlihut to write a get, to culpability for Sabbath violations? || Recollection of an averah is a technical requirement regarding korbanot, which the OP asked nothing about. Why are you mentioning it? || In what way are the two rulings of Rambam in conflict? (I see no contradiction between אין דעתו נכונה ומיושבת and נטרפה דעתו, ונמצאת דעתו משובשת תמיד. Even if there were a difference, you bring no evidence that statement in Hilkhot Geirushin is based on a universal definition of shoteh, so there is [cont.]

Comment: [cont] no evidence that it would even be relevant to the discussion at hand. || Even if the aforementioned cases are both solely dependent on a universal definition of shoteh, we still only see that you are unable to clarify the opinion of even one codifier regarding the definition of shoteh. That isn't an answer, but rather an admission of defeat. Furthermore, there is much reason to think that a hilkhot Shabbat question is not a shoteh question is isolation, since it has the added caveat of מלאכת מחשבת. Additionally , the discussion of teshuva for minors indicates that even were hillul [cont

Comment: Shabbat totally identical with every other area of halakha, the obligation to repent is still likely based on individual circumstances, and not based on the mere title of "minor", or "shoteh". || Lastly, your answer appears internally contradictory regarding the crucial point of the equivalence of psychosis and shtut. First you write `The definition of psychotic in DSM is not fully equivalent to the definition of Shoyte in halacha.` but then you write that you dont even know the definition of shote! "that the matter is not so easy to decide. there was a famous Get in 1766-1767 with [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] several discussions about Shoyte." In summary, I would delete this answer in the meantime, and try to clarify the following points a) what category of person is subject to the teshuva requirement b) does person in the midst of a psychotic episode qualify? c) What sort of Sabbath violations require teshuvah d) must one do teshuva for an averah he does not recall. Hatslaha rabba!